# Minimax AI in python

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, numpy-ndarray, minmax

I'm trying to create a minimax type AI which would go through 4 layers of moves and try to pick out the best possible move based on a certain heuristic. The thing is in my state machine if I ever reach a node which is an illegal move then I return the value None instead of a normal point value that my heuristic function would give. When dealing with this in my minimax function I'm kind of unsure how to go about it in the best way. So far it kind of looks like this and was wondering if this makes sense.

```
def ai_min_max(board, ai_mancala, player_mancala, ai_choices, player_choices, target_depth, cur_depth, maxTurn, position):
    #base case where we call our heuristic function to tell us what the value of this state is
    if cur_depth == target_depth :
        #return the heuristic value for this state
        return first_heuristic(board, ai_mancala, player_mancala, ai_choices, player_choices, position)

    #if we are currently on a level where we are maximizing our function
    if maxTurn :
        #set the value to negative infinity
        max_eval = float("-inf")
        #go through the 10 possible choices you can make
        for x in range(len(ai_choices)) :
            new_position = position + [x]
            my_eval = ai_min_max(board, ai_mancala, player_mancala, ai_choices, player_choices, target_depth, cur_depth +1, False, new_position)
            #update the current max only if we have a valid movement, if not then do not update
            if my_eval is not None:
                max_eval = max(max_eval, my_eval)
        if max_eval == float("-inf") :
            return float("inf")
        return max_eval

    #if it is the minimizing player's turn
    else :
        min_eval = float("inf")
        for x in range(len(player_choices)) :
            new_position = position + [x]
            my_eval = ai_min_max(board, ai_mancala, player_mancala, ai_choices, player_choices, target_depth, cur_depth +1, True, new_position)
            if my_eval is not None:
                min_eval = min(min_eval, my_eval)
        #if there were no valid moves
        if min_eval == float("inf") :
            return float("-inf")
        return min_eval
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically in a minimax implementation you never actually make a recursive call on illegal moves - these are never generated in the first place. But, in some instances it can be easier (or less expensive) to actually apply the move to find out whether it is legal or not. For instance, if you have to apply a complex computation to find out if a move is legal, then you don't want to do it twice (once when you generate potential moves and once when you search on them). So, I will assume this is the case here.

Given this, does it make sense to return a special value as in your code above.

No, there is a better approach. At a min node you can return -inf to the parent when the move is illegal, and at a max node you can return inf to the parent. In this way, the illegal moves have the worse possible value, and will be handled naturally by the rest of the search without any other special cases. This makes the main minimax/alpha-beta loop much simpler.

The only complication to this is if a max player at the root has all moves losing it might return the illegal move. You can handle this case outside the main search - where testing a single move is very cheap compared to the full search - and just return any legal move if the move returned was illegal.

Comment: Thank you very much, all of this makes a lot of sense! How I ended up doing it was exactly what you said with the returning -inf and positive inf to my previous function calls!